# React Always use optional operator when displaying data from API?

Tags: reactjs

I am abit confused with react getting api why i always have to use optional operator while fetching data to react element

here is an example :

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
const getData= async (e) => {  
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("/data", {}, { withCredentials: true });
        setData(data)    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    getData();
},[])

return (

  // why i always have to use ?. to display the data ?
  {data?.restData.map(el => {
         return <div>{el.name}</div>
 })}
   )
```

why I have to use **?.** to be able to display the data or I receive an error that the data is undefined, is there a better way to display data?

because when I run the app I get 2 console logs the first one is undefined and then the data , Am I missing something ?

Comment: This is how react works. When it first render your component there's no data yet. Then you set it so that it's there when the component rerenders.

Comment: but why react render 2 times , first time the data is always undefined then it gets the data , is there away to always render only once ?

NOTE : that react.StrictMode is off

Comment: It's because it'll run without any data present and cause a null reference error. Whereas the optional chaining operator will check null before progressing.

Comment: `is there away to always render only once ?` No, it takes time to load the data. The first render will always happen before the data exists. Then once it does exist, you set state and render again.

Comment: i understand now thank you guys for explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Because your `data` could be undefined. When you initialse the state, `data` is actually undefined. Without the `?.` it would throw an error, that `data` is undefined. Now it would just do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

Your initial state is undefined. So if you tried to do `data.restData`, you would throw an exception, because `undefined` does not have a `restData` property. using `?.` is a very simple way to handle that case.

If you prefer to do something more complicated, you could do that too, which may or may not use optional chaining. For example:

```
if (!data) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
} else {
  return (
    <>
      {data.restData.map(el => {
        return <div>{el.name}</div>
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for this , can i do a loading screen before displaying the data with this code ?

Comment: Yes, i've included an example of that (just a simple piece of text sayiing "loading...", but you could make it as elaborate as you want)

Comment: its a great idea to build a loading screen before loading the data from the server , thank you for this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set your initial state first:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({restData: []});
```

Then you can write:

```
data.restData.map...
```

Comment: this is also working , thank you for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Because initial state is undefined, if you don't wanna use `?.` define the initial state:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({restData: []});
```